# Return a parametrized object in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, extends

I wrote a simple class that parametrizes an object inside it

```
public class FooToReturn<T extends Foo>{
    T object;
    public T getObject(){
       return object;
    }
}
```

and some function in another class needs to return a parametrized instance of it, like

```
public FooToReturn doSomething(){
   ....
   return new FooToReturn<ChildFoo>();
}
```

Is it possible to just keep the return `FooToReturn` in the declaration or will it give me error at runtime? Eclipse already gives me this warning at the function declaration.

```
References to generic type FooToReturn<T> should be parameterized
```

Comment: Well try it!! But no it won't give you an error at runtime, because of type erasure... Basically generics in Java give you more safety at compile time than at runtime.

Comment: Change the signature of `doSomething` to `public FooReturn<? extends Foo> doSomething()`

Comment: Yes! That did the trick. However, I now need to declare
`protected void notify (FooToReturn<? extends Foo> fooToReturn){
        
        otherObject.update(this, fooToReturn.getEvent());
        
    }`

and the `update` is overloaded various types that T can assume. It still wants Foo and not FooChild as argument. What can I do?